# How to increase the area of ​touch?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want the touch area to be off the edge without padding. All the icons in the header. How can I do this?

I tried to add an indentation style for the icon. But it does not look beautiful. And yet there is an area without touch.

[Look at here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORQ9J.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the touchable area by using 'hitSlop', [See document here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#hitslop)

Comment: How can I use it for react navigation ?

Comment: Thanks. It works. 
<HeaderButton
      hitSlop={{top: 15, bottom: 15, left: 15, right: 15}} ... />